# How does one measure the effect of latency on potential returns?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading-systems, market-making, sharpe-ratio, latency

I am looking to evaluate the hypothetical advantage one trading system has over another in terms of the possible returns given their latency.

Irene Aldridge wrote a piece ([How Profitable Are High-Frequency Trading Strategies?](http://www.finalternatives.com/node/9271)) which describes how to relate holding time to Sharpe ratio, although her approach seems somewhat arbitrary.

As I am investigating the effect of latency on market making strategies, I have modified this approach to use the maximal spread in a time frame to be the return and the spread's variance as risk (as the spread proxies for the risk of the market maker).

Are there any other metrics I can make use of? Does my approach thus far seem reasonable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An interesting starting point is [The Cost of Latency](http://moallemi.com/ciamac/papers/latency-2009.pdf) by Moallemi and Saglam. After setting up a simple order execution problem --- in which a trader must chose between a market order and a limit order and guarantee execution over a fixed interval $[0,T]$, they proceed to derive a (complex) close form solution for the optimal strategy and evaluate the impact of latency on trading costs. In particular, they derive a simple expression to approximate the cost of latency when the latency is small (i.e. in the limit $\Delta t \to 0$, where $\Delta t$ denotes some measure of the latency of the trading system). In terms of price volatility $\sigma$, the bid-ask spread $\delta$, the cost of latency is

$$\frac{\sigma\sqrt{\Delta t}}{\delta}\sqrt{\log \frac{\delta^2}{2 \pi \sigma^2 \Delta t}}$$

The profile of the latency cost according to their model is (Fig 7, [The Cost of Latency](http://moallemi.com/ciamac/papers/latency-2009.pdf) by Moallemi and Saglam)

[image]

The proceed to evaluate the historical cost of latency and the implied latency for a basket of NYSE stocks (Figs 8 and 9, [The Cost of Latency](http://moallemi.com/ciamac/papers/latency-2009.pdf) by Moallemi and Saglam)

[image]
[image]

Comment: nice answer @Ryogi

Comment: The thing is that when $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ the volatility $\sigma$ is challenging to estimate...